# Node/add within a block?

Tags: 6, blocks

Is it possible to have a block that shows the node create page for a content type, and which would disappear once the node has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Panels to display a node create form anywhere you like. With a bit of extra config, you could probably make it disappear when a node exists. Panels allows you to set visibility rules to determine whether to show content.

Comment: Ah yes, this'd work well. Cheers.